# Implement review schema on about page to get star rich snippets and have "sameAs" markup on your home page to get the stars for that too?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

A few months back I started up a new project and I would like to use rich snippets now.

In specific, I would like to implement a possibility of giving my business a rating on a specific page (let's say the "About us" page) instead of each product individually (since indexing for each product will be tough). I would use a service such as TrustPilot.

If I am correct, Google might display the stars in the results for the about us page, since ratings are appropriate there.

Question: Is it then possible to duplicate/forward (`sameAs`) these results and display them on the homepage as well, so Google picks these up for the mainpage? I couldn't see why that is breaching the terms and I have seen competitors do similar things.

Comment: Do you have an example of a home page getting review stars? I've never seen it.

Answer (score 1):

If your home page represents a local business or one of the following types and has the appropriate structured data, then user reviews about your business can be presented by Google in rich results with stars. Check the following **[google recommendations for type Review](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet)**:

> You can supply ratings for the following content types:
>
> Books
>
> Local businesses
>
> Movies
>
> Music
>
> Products
>
> Recipes
>
> Software App
>
> Refer clearly to a specific product or service by nesting the review
>   within the markup of another schema.org type, such as schema.org/Book
>   or schema.org/LocalBusiness, or by using a schema.org type as a value
>   for the itemReviewed property. Make sure the reviews and ratings you
>   mark up are readily available to users from the marked-up page. It
>   should be immediately obvious to users that the page has review
>   content.
>
> If the review snippet is for a local business, you must follow these
>   additional guidelines:
>
> **Ratings must be sourced directly from users**.
>   Don't rely on human editors to create, curate, or compile ratings
>   information for local businesses; instead, use critic review
>   structured data. **Sites must collect ratings information directly from
>   users and not from other sites**.

It may also be useful for you to check the following Google recommendations from the guide **[Follow the structured data guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)**:

> Don't mark up irrelevant or misleading content, such as fake
>   reviews...

**[Google’s guide on spam in structured data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175)** also has interesting information:

> Review written by the site or person providing the service Reviews
>   must not be written or provided by the business or content provider
>   unless they are customer, independent, and unpaid editorial reviews.

Thus, your structured data from the third-party TrustPilot website may be deemed irrelevant.